# Sonarqube 6.0: How to override the issue description when they're created from a sensor plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm creating issues from a sensor whit the folowing code:

```
NewIssue newIssue = context.newIssue();
RuleKey ruleKey = RuleKey.of("horus", "H0001");
newIssue.forRule(ruleKey).at(newIssue.newLocation().on(file).at(file.selectLine(linea))).save();
```

But I can't figure how to override the issue description from the default one to something like: "The value of the metric is xxx which is larger than the yyy allowed". Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

The NewLocation class contains the method `message(string message)` https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/sensor/issue/NewIssueLocation.java#L54

So you can change your code to:

`newIssue.forRule(ruleKey).at(newIssue.newLocation().message("My Message").on(file).at(file.selectLine(linea))).save();`